# Assigning auto-implemented property to itself with null coalescing operator "??"

Tags: c#, .net, properties, nullable, null-coalescing-operator

I have an auto-implemented property which takes the default value. This property reads its value from a database, but if that's null it should take its default value.

```
    // Variable Declaration
    public bool IsSoundEffects { get; set; } = true;

    // Usage
    bool? readFromDB = null;    // Get it from Database assume its NULL
    IsSoundEffects = readFromDB ?? IsSoundEffects;
```

Is assigning `IsSoundEffects` to itself a usual practice if a previous database read results in null?

What should do the trick to make this code organized and readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. As an alternative, [GetValueOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.8#System_Nullable_1_GetValueOrDefault__0_) will also work.

```
IsSoundEffects = readFromDb.GetValueOrDefault(IsSoundEffects);
```

Either of these are good solutions if your `readFromDb` was really a method with parameters because you can have clean syntax such as the below

```
IsSoundEffects = readFromDb(some, parameters).GetValueOrDefault(IsSoundEffects);
IsSoundEffects = readFromDb(some, parameters) ?? IsSoundEffects;
```

The former was your only option prior to the `??` operator being introduced into C#.

If the "assign to self" is distasteful, then avoid the initial assignment, and do it explicitly elsewhere, e.g.

```
public bool IsSoundEffects { get; set; }
...
IsSoundEffects = readFromDb(some, parameters).GetValueOrDefault(true);
IsSoundEffects = readFromDb(some, parameters) ?? true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple

```
if(readFromDB != null) IsSoundEffects = readFromDB;
```

So that you can avoid the assignment of same value when readFromDB is null.